# Randomize order of Wordpress results

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, random, shuffle

I'm trying to add a random order to my wordpress results with the code below. I've been told an array that calls a random number might work. Or somehow trying to include the orderby="rand" parameter somewhere.

```
class WC_Widget_Brand_Thumbnails_MJ extends WP_Widget {

    /** Variables to setup the widget. */
    var $woo_widget_cssclass;
    var $woo_widget_description;
    var $woo_widget_idbase;
    var $woo_widget_name;

    /** constructor */
    function __construct() {

        /* Widget variable settings. */
        $this->woo_widget_name          = __('WooCommerce Brand Thumbnails MJ', 'wc_brands' );
        $this->woo_widget_description   = __( 'Show a RANDOM Brand (Supplier) Thumbnail', 'wc_brands' );
        $this->woo_widget_idbase        = 'wc_brands_brand_thumbnails';
        $this->woo_widget_cssclass      = 'widget_brand_thumbnails';

        /* Widget settings. */
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => $this->woo_widget_cssclass, 'description' => $this->woo_widget_description );

        /* Create the widget. */
        $this->WP_Widget( $this->woo_widget_idbase, $this->woo_widget_name, $widget_ops );
    }

    /** @see WP_Widget */
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        
        $exclude = array_map( 'intval', explode( ',', $instance['exclude'] ) );
        $order = $instance['orderby'] == 'name' ? 'asc' : 'desc';

        $brands = get_terms( 'product_brand', array( 'hide_empty' => $instance['hide_empty'], 'orderby' => $instance['orderby'], 'exclude' => $exclude, 'number' => $instance['number'], 'order' => $order ) );

        if ( ! $brands ) 
            return;

        echo $before_widget;
        
        if ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) )
            echo $before_title . $instance['title'] . $after_title;

        woocommerce_get_template( 'widgets/brand-thumbnailsMJ.php', array(
            'brands'    => $brands,
            'columns'   => $instance['columns']
        ), 'woocommerce-brands', untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) ) . '/templates/' );

        echo $after_widget;
    }

    /** @see WP_Widget->update */
    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( stripslashes( $new_instance['title'] ) );
        $instance['columns'] = strip_tags( stripslashes( $new_instance['columns'] ) );
        $instance['orderby'] = strip_tags( stripslashes( $new_instance['orderby'] ) );
        $instance['exclude'] = strip_tags( stripslashes( $new_instance['exclude'] ) );
        $instance['hide_empty'] = strip_tags( stripslashes( $new_instance['hide_empty'] ) );
        $instance['number'] = strip_tags( stripslashes( $new_instance['number'] ) );
        
        if ( ! $instance['columns'] )
            $instance['columns'] = 1;
            
        if ( ! $instance['orderby'] )
            $instance['orderby'] = 'name';
            
        if ( ! $instance['exclude'] )
            $instance['exclude'] = '';
            
        if ( ! $instance['hide_empty'] )
            $instance['hide_empty'] = 0;
            
        if ( ! $instance['number'] )
            $instance['number'] = '';
        
        return $instance;
    }

    /** @see WP_Widget->form */
    function form( $instance ) {
        if ( ! isset( $instance['hide_empty'] ) ) 
            $instance['hide_empty'] = 0;
        if ( ! isset( $instance['orderby'] ) ) 
            $instance['orderby'] = 'name';
        ?>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'wc_brands') ?></label>
                <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ); ?>" value="<?php if ( isset ( $instance['title'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $instance['title'] ); ?>" />
            </p>
            
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'columns' ); ?>"><?php _e('Columns:', 'wc_brands') ?></label>
                <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'columns' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'columns' ) ); ?>" value="<?php if ( isset ( $instance['columns'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $instance['columns'] ); else echo '1'; ?>" />
            </p>
            
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>"><?php _e('Number:', 'wc_brands') ?></label>
                <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'number' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'number' ) ); ?>" value="<?php if ( isset ( $instance['number'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $instance['number'] ); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('All', 'wc_brands'); ?>" />
            </p>
            
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'exclude' ); ?>"><?php _e('Exclude:', 'wc_brands') ?></label>
                <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'exclude' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'exclude' ) ); ?>" value="<?php if ( isset ( $instance['exclude'] ) ) echo esc_attr( $instance['exclude'] ); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e('None', 'wc_brands'); ?>" />
            </p>
            
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'hide_empty' ); ?>"><?php _e('Hide empty brands:', 'wc_brands') ?></label>
                <select id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'hide_empty' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'hide_empty' ) ); ?>">
                    <option value="1" <?php selected( $instance['hide_empty'], 1 ) ?>><?php _e('Yes', 'wc_brands') ?></option>
                    <option value="0" <?php selected( $instance['hide_empty'], 0 ) ?>><?php _e('No', 'wc_brands') ?></option>
                </select>
            </p>
            
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'orderby' ); ?>"><?php _e('Order by:', 'wc_brands') ?></label>
                <select id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'orderby' ) ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'orderby' ) ); ?>">
                    <option value="name" <?php selected( $instance['orderby'], 'name' ) ?>><?php _e('Name', 'wc_brands') ?></option>
                    <option value="count" <?php selected( $instance['orderby'], 'count' ) ?>><?php _e('Count', 'wc_brands') ?></option>
                    
                </select>
            </p>
        <?php
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to randomise the order of the `$brands` returned from the `get_terms` calls you could simple shuffle the results by calling `shuffle($brands);`

If you want to be able to choose whether the results are shuffled or not based on the `orderby` parameter, then you would need a little more code.

```
$args = array( 'hide_empty' => $instance['hide_empty'], 'orderby' => $instance['orderby'], 'exclude' => $exclude, 'number' => $instance['number'], 'order' => $order );
if ($instance['orderby'] == 'random') {
  $args['orderby'] = 'none';
  $brands = get_terms( 'product_brand', $args );
  shuffle($brands);
}
else {
  $brands = get_terms( 'product_brand', $args );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried pasting the code into all the functions but the results were not randomised. How would I write and call the shuffle ($brands) function. Sorry I'm a little new to php.

Comment: I added this form element to call your code.  <option value="random" <?php selected( $instance['orderby'], 'random' ) ?>><?php _e('Random', 'wc_brands') ?></option>

Comment: In the `widget` function, you should add the call `shuffle($brands);` after the line that starts with `$brands = get_terms(`. Alternatively, replace that line completely with the block of code I provided in my answer if you want to control the shuffling with the orderby parameter.

Comment: Hmm, neither of those options worked. Could it be something to do with the extract ( $args ); as to why $args isn't working?

Comment: If just adding the `shuffle($brands);` call didn't work, then the other solution I suggested won't do any better. I'm afraid of don't have any other suggestions.

Comment: Something else occurred to me - it might just be a caching issue. Try commenting out the entire contents of the `widget` function, which should make the widget disappear. If it doesn't, then it must be being cached somehow. If so, you could try clearing your browser cache, or disabling any wordpress caching functionality, or as a last resort restart the web server.

Comment: Hmm thanks for those suggestions. I tried adding `shuffle ($brands)` directly to the get terms array, and I got this null return `Warning: shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /www/customers/independentliving.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-brands/classes/widgets/class-wc-widget-brand-thumbnailsMJ.php on line 44`

Comment: That means that `get_terms` must be returning null sometimes. Add the call to `shuffle($brands);` after this line: `if ( ! $brands ) return;` That way, if it's null it will just return and display nothing.

Comment: Yeh the widget vanished doing that. What does it mean if it is returning null?

Comment: But that would mean the widget would have vanished even if you didn't have the `shuffle` call there. Have you made other changes to the code that might have caused it to break? Perhaps rewind everything back to how it was initially. Make sure the widget is visible. Then add nothing but the `shuffle($brands);` call after the `if ( ! $brands ) return;`.

Comment: AH HA! Ok so I got the functionality working. Your comment helped me track it back to the problem that stops it from working, which is as soon as I enter a number of "1" (to only show one result it breaks.

Comment: Just bother you a little further, do you have any idea how to hard-code the results to display only one result?

Comment: Something like `$brands = array_slice($brands, 0, 1);` should work. Add that after the call to `shuffle($brands)` assuming you want a random element. This may not be the most effecient solution, but I don't know Wordpress well enough to suggest anything better.

Comment: That did it. Excellent, thank you for all of your help and time :)